# What is the benefit of using google cloud storage instead of google cloud sql for saving files

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

So what makes google cloud storage preferred choice for saving files. As I know google cloud storage is saving the file as blob so it is immutable and cannot be edited.

Comment: it's absolutely different things - "filesystem" and "rdbms"

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Artamonov It's not problem that is different. I'm asking only for files. So I want to know where is better to save files , because I don't see the benefit of using cloud storage. Also there can be other solutions like big query or saving directly in the datastore. For example the datastore may be better because of it's scalability , but I'm not asking for this. I have to make choice between google cloud sql and google cloud storage. Thank you for the down vote

Comment: for files filesystem fits better that rdbms, just because it designed exactly for this. and I didn't down vote, thanks for blaming

Comment: I downvoted, and also voted to close fyi.

Comment: Why. Although there is some answer that I accepted I still don't understand what "designed exactly for this" means. Yes google cloud storage is designed for files and what then. I'm not able to edit those files, then for what is useful except for direct serving file. There is not concurrency in reading the file and so on. You don't have real folders and nothing more then a real RDBM. That is why I'm asking. So I don't think that my question is without any purpose. I can then save the file and serve it setting the type of content on my own. The browsers GET request cannot make the difference.

Comment: A) it's not a programming question and B) Finding out the difference between a bucket for files and a SQL database is well within your capability. The consensus will decide on your question, people are free to upvote and not vote to close. If you can't think of a use for such a system where you can't edit the files and don't' have "real" folders (hint - it does) then you don't need to use it. When you have a use case that it fits, then use it. Until then...

Comment: @makkasi it better to provide requirements, what exactly you want to do with your data. also, why you didn't consider google datastore then? still a lot of work to write an FS layer on top of it, but it will be easer that doing it on top of cloud sql. but still depends on requirements, of course

Comment: What are the requirements that I have:
____1.managing many files, like about terabyte of files. 
____2.every file could be merged with an other file on the fly
____3.currently using cloud sql for the other data (but would be wrong to use it for so many files and documents, because of the performance of the mysql)
____4.yes we need reliability and performance
____5.may be in future searching inside those files (not sure for this one)
____6.going for lower price against the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the main aspect of your website/application is a database (as is often the case), check out Google Cloud SQL. Again it allows you to host your MySQL database on Google’s infrastructure, increasing the speed, reliability and security.

Whereas Google Cloud Storage enables application developers to store their data on Google’s infrastructure with very high reliability, performance and availability, and can be used to distribute large data objects to users via direct download.